# Не получается добавить библиотеку с GitHub в android-проект

Tags: android, android-studio, библиотеки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно добавить библиотеку CircleImageView-master с GitHub. Делаю все по инструкции:
"Клонировать библиотеку на ваш компьютер.
В Android studio выбрать File > New > Import Module, после чего выбрать библиотеку.
В build.gradle добавить

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':******')
    // ...
}
```

Выполнить Build > Make Project"

Вылезает такая ошибка:
"could not get unknown property GROUP for object for type org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer"

Comment: Вы забыли добавить текст ошибки.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: "could not get unknown property GROUP for object for type org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer"

Comment: о том, как подключить библиотеку, обычно написано [в описании](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView#gradle) самой библиотеки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы тащите за собой оригинальный `build.gradle`, который пытается опубликовать артефакт на maven репозитории...

Надо просто написать:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
```

Тогда либа подтянется из репозитория maven

Comment: Прописываю, как вы сказали. Ошибка остается

Comment: @Electra вдобавок ко всему надо просто выкинуть все исходники либы из своего проекта... я полагал вам это понятно, вижу что требуется пояснение

Comment: Да, подчистила и все получилось. Опыта нет, в первый раз делаю. Спасибо за помощь!